# SharePoint 2013 Site collection restore to another SharePoint 2013 error?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, error, backup

I have backup of site collection from on SharePoint 2013 which is down.

I want to restore it to the new SharePoint 2013 site collection.

Below is my command:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity <http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test> -Path <\\AF-SP-SRV\SharePoint\hrc.bak> [-DatabaseServer <af-dbt1-srv>] [-DatabaseName <WSS_Content_test>] [-HostHeader <Host header>] [-Force] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

Wwhen I run the command it gives error see image:

[image]

Comment: could you please give us the exact command which you are running after others recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The correct sintax is:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test -Path \\AF-SP-SRV\SharePoint\hrc.bak -DatabaseServer af-dbt1-srv -DatabaseName WSS_Content_test -HostHeader Host header -Force -GradualDelete -Verbose
```

You do not have to use `<` and `>` and neither `[` and `]`

[Restore-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ff607788.aspx)

Comment: It give error the web application: http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test can not be found

Comment: do you have the permission to create a site collection? Does a site collection with that name already exist?

Comment: Yes I just created it, I first created one empty content database with name wss_content_test and locked other content databases than I created site collection with name test which url is: http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test and it is correct but I don't know

Comment: try to wrap the url with "" ( "http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test")

Comment: Full Error message: Restore-SPSite: The web application at http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test counld not be found.
verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content,
the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application

Comment: does a get-spsite on that url work fine?

Comment: Yes the get-spsite works on my site url: http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23014/discussion-between-nk-sp-and-mehdi-jalal).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you have just copied all the arguments for the cmdlt *Restore-SpSite*. You only need to use some of the arguments to be able to restore a backup.

This should work for you.

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test" -Path "\\AF-SP-SRV\SharePoint\hrc.bak" -DatabaseServer af-dbt1-srv -DatabaseName WSS_Content_test
```

Just make sure that the account that are gonna restore the backup has permission to the location where the backup is.

And it's always good to run powershell/management shell as an administrator.